# log in to v20z console using serial management

Tags: solaris, x86, lom

I have a Netra T1 (SPARC) which has LOM that enable to log in to the OS console locally for troubleshooting without plug in a monitor and keyboard.

I also have a SunFire V20z (x86) which has a SP. However I do not find any equivalent command to reach the console. It would not be ideal for me to bring along monitor and keyboard to the data center for troubleshooting locally.

For example, I accidentally messup the OS network configuration and unable to log in the OS. I have to log to the console through serial management/LOM to troubleshoot it. However it seem doesn't work in x86 machine. Is there anyway I can able to do the same thing on x86 machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SP doesn't have a straight serial command interface like the LOM's of old.

It is accessed over the network instead, with IPMI or SSH.

You can find some information about configuring the SP network interface and accounts [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19121-01/sf.v20z/817-5246-16/chap2.html).

Comment: i see. let's say i move my server to another network and they required static network configuration and i unable to ssh. How would i configure the network?

Comment: If you have physical access to the machine then you can reconfigure it from the front panel. If you don't then you could bring up an IP alias from the old range on a machine within the same network and reconfigure from there.

Comment: Oh. I understand the SP's IP can be reconfigure from the front panel. But what I try to ask is about the network interface bge0 and bge1, can it be reconfigure as well on the front panel? or there is alternative?

Comment: `bge0` and `bge1` would be platform interfaces presented to the OS. These can only be configured by the OS. If you can connect to the SP then you should be able to setup platform console redirection and access the OS console. The precise instructions will depend on what OS you are using.

Comment: Try these instructions - http://docs.sun.com/source/817-5249-17/chapter4.html#pgfId-1012951

Answer (score 0):

Once you are logged in to the SP on the V20z, you issue the following command to connect to the console:

`platform console`

To escape back to the SP, use `^Ec.` i.e. control-E, then lowercase `c` and finally a period `.`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be out of date, but --

I have some V20z systems running CentOS 4.x.  They come with the IPMI pieces.  I have successfully rewritten SP network parameters from the running OS through use of the ipmitool.

For example:

```
# ipmitool lan print 1 | grep IP
IP Address Source       : Static Address
IP Address              : 10.16.5.252
IP Header               : TTL=0x40 Flags=0x00 Precedence=0x00 TOS=0x10
Default Gateway IP      : 10.16.15.254
Backup Gateway IP       : 0.0.0.0
# ipmitool lan set 1 ipaddr 1.2.3.4
# ipmitool lan set 2 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

...etc

This is much less tedious than punching things into the front panel.

(oh wait, I have the problem backwards, you are trying to reconfigure the OS through the SP.  Never mind.)